# WeakSet: garbage collection doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I've just learned about WeakSet, that it stores only references to real objects so after removing the object, it is available no longer using that WeakSet.

I've checked it and it doesn't work!
Example for Chrome ver. 63. running from the console:

```
 let obj = {'is':1}
 let ws = new WeakSet([obj])
 obj = null
 console.log(ws) // still ws has old obj inside
```

https://i.gyazo.com/96a770e08c6dd57f362756f0581e8a77.png

What have I misunderstood?

Comment: I guess it's simply because the garbage collector did not have time to run.